# Visual Studio 2013 Outlook plugin, installing on a restricted citrix enviroment

Tags: visual-studio, outlook, add-in

I have been struggling to figure this out.
We have made a Outlook Add-In in Visual Studio 2013.
I can install this using the .vsto that they provide without a problem on a windows machine.
Now I try the same thing, placing the .vsto on the citrix server, installing this works fine, although it does a call to the internet which isn't allowed, so I had to work around that (anybody know why it calls to the internet? and what?).
Than I got it installed at the server, go to the thin clients, its right there, the only thing I have to do is activate it.
The second I activate it, it runs an executable, which obviously is not allowed, and I cannot activate it on the client.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an MSI installer for the add-in. See [Deploying an Office Solution by Using Windows Installer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc442767.aspx) for more information.

Comment: I have used that tutorial to build an installer using InstallShield, and set the settings to ALLUSERS=1.
Problem 1 was that I build it in a visual studio project which was not working because either 1, I didn't have InstallShield on my Citrix enviroment or don't have Visual Studio on my packaging machine.
So I used a 'normal' version of InstallShield with license we already had.
What does this is set the settings, and unpack the package into C:/Program Files/[ProjectName]/[Product]
After that I still have to run the .vsto as an installer to get it to work.